# Is it possible to add a wordpress function call inside another function call?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I don't know if this is possible, or if there is a workaround, but I need to add a shortcode to my single.php template. However, inside the shortcode, I ideally need to call author meta data so that the shortcode renders the correct information...

It is something like this:

```html
<? php do_shortcode('[form id="<? php the_author_meta( 'authorspecificformid' ); ?>"]') ?>
```

I know this doesn't work, but is there a workaround I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can construct this shortcode like this :

```
<?php
$authorId = get_the_author_meta("authorspecificformid");
echo do_shortcode("[form id=\"$authorId\"]");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Sadly that hasn't worked :-/

Comment: what doesn't work ? edit your question to add details and debug otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I inserted the code into my single.php template and the metadata - the "authorspecificformid" isn't being pulled into the shortcode when the posts load

Comment: Got it working - it was just missing the echo before do... THANK YOU!